# How to reduce JOINs in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT q.type,
      q.author_id author,
      q.deleted,
      q.deleter_id,
      COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) answers_num,
      COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) votes_num,
FROM qanda q
LEFT  JOIN qanda a ON q.id = a.related
LEFT  JOIN votes v on q.id = v.post_id
WHERE q.id = ?
```

It works well. Just I need to add one more thing (which returns a boolean by `EXISTS`) in the `SELECT` statement. This:

```
EXISTS (SELECT a.id, sum(vot.value) total_votes
        FROM qanda q
        LEFT JOIN qanda a on q.id = a.related
        LEFT JOIN votes vot ON a.id = vot.post_id
        WHERE q.type = 0         -- this is a question
          AND a.related = 1315   -- getting answers
        GROUP BY a.id
        HAVING total_votes
        ORDER BY total_votes DESC
        LIMIT1
) as HasAUpvotedAnswer
```

Ok, it works well too. But I'm worried about the performance. As you can see, the `JOIN`s of those two queries above (which will be combined finally) are similar. How can make them more optimal?

In other word, how can I combine those two above queries in the most optimal case?

Comment: Could you share a couple rows from your db with a representative example of what you're trying to do, and the expected result?

Comment: @MarcinJ Conceptually I'm trying to make a "you are not able to delete your question because it has one upvoted answer or two answers or etc .." for a Q/A website like SO.

Comment: do the multiple rows you receive through the LEFT JOIN have the same data? if so, you could basically DISTINCT your resultset. if not, i'd have a look on the join conditions if you can add more conditions to make it distinct

Comment: @stack Currently I don't know what's the problem you're facing, that's why sharing a couple rows that represent what you're trying to do is important. In your EXISTS subquery you have hardcoded some IDs, so we can't figure out what the join conditions for the corelated subquere are. Paste a couple rows from `qanda` and `votes` and then rows that you expect out as a result of your query. People don't like to guess what is it you're trying to do, how your data is laid out, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your code could be that y can use a single query  using conditional for sum

```
SELECT q.type,
      q.author_id author,
      q.deleted,
      q.deleter_id,
      COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) answers_num,
      COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) votes_num,
      IF (SUM(
        CASE WHEN q.type  = 0 AND a.related = 1315
          THEN v.value  else  0 END) > 0,1,0) 
      HasAUpvotedAnswer
FROM qanda q
LEFT  JOIN qanda a ON q.id = a.related
LEFT  JOIN votes v on q.id = v.post_id
WHERE q.id = ?
```

Comment: 1) The parentheses in the behind of `HasAUpvotedAnswer` is redundant. 2) It throws: `Unknown column 'v.votes' in 'field list'`

Comment: answer updated ..  v.value and not v.votes .. votes is table with alias  v

Comment: Currently the value of `HasAUpvotedAnswer` is `6` *(for my real dataset)*. I was expected to be a boolean *(either `0` or `1`, like what `EXISTS` returns)*

Comment: added  an if sum > 0 for 1 or 0

Comment: Well apparently it works ..! But I guess the logic is wrong. Since we're not even count the vote value of answers. Since we're not joining answers table (`qanda` as `a`) with `votes` table.

Comment: You know, I've added one more vote to one of answers of question `1315`, but still the result of `HasAUpvotedAnswer` was `6`

Comment: show me a data sample  ..  .with the if ( ) can't return 6 and the table involved  are the same  .. so you don't need  the qanda as  a  with vote ..

Comment: no, I've removed `IF` to get `6`. thank you anyway, upvote

Comment: if you need  a boolend (0,1) you need  if  sum > 0  then 1 else  0

Comment: yeah as I said, when I add `IF`, the result will be a boolean (as expected). But honestly I'm worried about the logic .. So I've removed that `IF` and done some tests to make sure about the logic. Let's ask, what's the reason of `6`? How that number is calculated? What does it mean? 6 votes is the total number of all answers?

Comment: is the sum() of v.value  ..what is the real content for v.value ??  is a number  .. is a string .?. i have assumed  is an integer  that you need to sum()

Comment: yes it is a number. Either `1` or `-1`. So it is the value of answers or question of both?

Comment: then is 6 is the sum of relative( + , - ) integer you have

Comment: See, rows are either question (`type = 0`) or answer (`type = 1`) in `qanda` table. Now, is `6` supposed to be the total sum of answer's vote or question's vote?

Comment: the `case  when `     is  a conditional that check for  type = 0 and  related = 1315  .. so the 6 are for rows that match this condition  .. as in your exist where condition

Comment: The fun part is there is no result for this query: `select * from qanda where type = 0 and related = 1315;`

Comment: a.related ..  and a is qanda for  q.id = a.related